# How can I make a function return its own type in C?

Tags: c, function, types

TL;DR What should the type of x be if `x = x();` is valid in C?

---

The whole story:

I am working on a simple game with multiple scenes. At first my code looked like this:

```c
enum {kSCENE_A, kSCENE_B} ecene = kSCENE_A;
int main() {
    while(1) {
        switch(scene) {
          case kSCENE_A:
            // Renders scene a
            // And possibly modifies `scene`
            break;
          case kSCENE_B:
            // Renders scene b
            // And possibly modifies `scene`
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However the `main` function is too verbose. I extracted the rendering part into different functions, but the `switch` still makes the code ugly. I defined a `scene_map` for this:

```c
typedef enum {
    kSCENE_A,
    kSCENE_B,

    kN_SCENES
} Scene;
Scene RenderSceneA();
Scene RenderSceneB();
int main() {
    Scene scene = kSCENE_A;
    Scene (*scene_map[kN_SCENES])();
    scene_map[kSCENE_A] = SceneA;
    scene_map[kSCENE_B] = SceneB;
    while(1) scene = scene_map[scene]();
}
```

But I wonder if it would be possible in C that I write the code in this, or some similar way:

```c
SomeType RenderSceneA();
SomeType RenderSceneB();
int main() {
    SomeType scene = RenderSceneA;
    while(1) scene = scene();
}
```

So what type should SomeType be, or can I only use `void *` for it? If the latter is true, how can I write this code in a clear manner than demonstrated in the second code block?

Comment: AFAICR, you can't do that in (standard C).  I seem to remember spending time on the problem back in the '90s, but nothing significant has changed since then that would affect this.  `x` would have to be a function pointer; it would have to be a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a function.  That gets hairy rather quickly — see [`signal()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) for an example of such a function.  Note that `signal()` does not return a pointer to its own type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I seem to remember spending time on the problem back in the '90s, but nothing significant has changed since then that would affect this one of the reasons of the C++ success. BTW I do not really their allergy to polymorphism

Comment: @0___________ If this is possible in C++, how should the code be like? I learned something about `std::function` but it does not seem to help with this. I tried `using SomeType = std::function<SomeType()>;` but of course it does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that will solve the problem.  Note that it uses `void (*)(void)` as a generic function pointer type, as opposed to `void *` which isn't guaranteed to work for function pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void (*f(void))(void);
void (*g(void))(void);

void (*f(void))(void)
{
    printf("This is f.\n");
    return (void (*)(void)) g;
}

void (*g(void))(void)
{
    printf("This is g.\n");
    return (void (*)(void)) f;
}

#define SRCALL(p)   ((void (*(*)(void))(void)) p())

int main(void)
{
    void (*(*p)(void))(void);

    p = f;

    p = SRCALL(p);
    p = SRCALL(p);
    p = SRCALL(p);

    return 0;
}
```

The function pointer casts are ugly, so I encapsulated them in the macro `SRCALL` (self-ref-call).  The output is:

```
This is f.
This is g.
This is f.
```

Comment: Though the use of `void *` is still present, `SRCALL` makes it look a lot better. Thanks.